# Resizing page and nav bar

Tags: android, html, css

My nav bar works as i want it to on normal sized pages/screens. How ever on phones or smaller screens it cuts off the black background of the nav bar and keeps the list contents. making them invisible, and a horizontal scroll bar appearing for what looks like nothing.

Preview of error:

[image: Preview of error]

My code in html is just a list, in css basic styling and position is 
margin: 0;
width: 1920px;

Ive tried setting it to 100%,but it just forces the nav bar text over the image, without extending the black bar. I just used 100% max width for the picture and it works fine.

All the tutorials i can find use boot strap, im not using boost strap as this is a practice school assignment and bootstrap isnt allowed in the final

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3y4yuxj/1/

Left out the head because it had personal info in it, but it doesnt affect the rest of the page so its cool

Comment: you tried bootstrap for this or not?

Comment: i havent, this is practice for an assessment. The assessment doesnt allow anything from a packaged editing tool.which im guessing includes bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{ 
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}
#serv{
  width:100%;
  margin-top: THE HEIGHT OF NAV;
}
```

Push this to nav and #serv.

Answer (score 0):

i think u haven't used navbar class in your navbar and refer my plunker and it is mobile responsive.

refer this Plunker.
use **ul<>tag** and **li<>tag**

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/5gvJYTgRcp6WzrN9cIOd?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: need to find a way to do it without bootstrap